# Keywords to describe people counting from a camera?

Tags: object-recognition

The subject matter is to count the number of people in a large room, wherein a camera is placed in a very high ceiling: an example would be Grand Central Station.   Faces are not visible: [the scalp (top of the head) is visible to the camera as shown in the link's video](http://zhreshold.github.io/logs/2014/04/16/head-detection/).

The goal: I would like to perform a Google literature search to assess the work that has been performed on overhead head recognition,  however, I am not sure what the best  keyword pairs: (scalp? head? people?) to describe the object that is to be recognized from a camera positioned in the ceiling (overhead? bird's eye? satellite?).  I'd like the search to return leading-edge (AI) techniques that benchmark results

Comment: Welcome to SE:AI!  At present, this question seems to be about keywords used in search.  Can you elaborate on how this relates to an AI algorithm?

Comment: Good question: image recognition (counting heads from a photo) is a class of problems for AI.  Hopefully my question is appropriate for this forum.

Answer (score 2):

I usually start with some papers and look at the references:

- Counting people using video cameras
- Sheng-Fuu Lin, Jaw-Yeh Chen, Hung-Xin Chao, Estimation of Number of People in Crowded Scenes Using Perspective Transformation,  IEEE Transactions on Systems, Man and Cybernetics, November 2001, Part A, Vol. 31, Issue 6, pp. 645-654.
- A.  C.  Davies,  J.  H.  Yin,  and S.  A.  Velastin,  Crowd monitoring using image processing,  Electronics  & Communication Engineering Journal, February  1995, Vol. 7, Issue 1, pp. 37-47.

By this technique you only find older work.

To find more recent articles, use Google scholar and find who cites the articles you investigated.

Always write them down (e.g. in your bibtex file) to keep track of what you looked at already.

Good luck!